# web3 error: BigNumber Error: "new BigNumber() not a base 16 number: "

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to make this simple Dapp work where I'm sending the variables nombre and edad to the setInstructor() function and then returned by the getInstructor() function. The problem is that I keep getting this error:

> BigNumber Error: "new BigNumber() not a base 16 number:

Any thoughts?

**Solidity**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;


contract Contrato {

  string fName;
  uint age;

  function setInstructor (string _fName, uint _age){
      fName = _fName;
      age = _age;
    
  }

  function getInstructor () public constant returns (string, uint){
      return (fName, age);
  }

}
```

**Web3**

```
var Contrato = web3.eth.contract(ABI);
var Contratito = Contrato.at(Address);

$("#button").click(function(){

    Contratito.setInstructor($("#nombre").val(), $("#edad").val(), function(error,result){if (!error) { console.log("bien") } else { console.error(error)}});

    Contratito.getInstructor(function(error,result){ if (!error) { $("#instructor").html(result[0] + " " + result[1])} else {console.error(error)}});

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by converting `$("#edad").val()` to a number rather than the string most likely returned.  If that doesn't work I would convert both `.val()` results to BigNumbers manually with `new BigNumber(...)`.

Let me know where that leaves us in the comments and hopefully we'll get this fixed quickly!

Comment: I tried the BigNumber() idea and also tested the function with given values instead of the requested from DOM, and also tried both altogether. But it still doesn't work. I read there's an issue with BigNumber() errors in the github repository but don't know how to solve it in this particular case.

Comment: Sorry wish I could do more then, but it seems to be a similar question on stackexchange (Gotta love the difference) already: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1741/what-does-the-web3-bignumber-not-a-base-16-number-error-mean

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this problem, I had to change the network my MetaMask browser extension was using to the one specified in the JavaScript code. Make sure the contract address is located on the network the MetaMask extension is using.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was related with *EVM* version being used.

I've to move from the default one (*bizantium*) to explicitly indicate the *homestead* version and it worked.

But attention *homestead* is the oldest one so I'm not sure of the implications of my choice. I did not try with other versions because it was a contract for test only purposes.

The command to compile the contract and indicate the *EVM* version (example):

```
solc --evm-version <VERSION> contract.sol
```

Reference: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/using-the-compiler.html#setting-the-evm-version-to-target